# Allure Cucumber Jvm Report for Cross browser and Parallel execution

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm, allure

Our test framework includes selenium + cucumber4 JVM + testing and allure report

Recently we updated our project to support parallel cross-browser execution using ThreadLocal. As a result of this, When I do parallel execution for cross-browser testing(in chrome and firefox) for sample feature as below

feature This is a test feature

Scenario This is a test scenario

One of the test results gets added to the retries tab of the allure report since the feature name and scenario names are the same and the test case count is displayed as 1 instead of 2.

I want to have the test results to be moved out of the retries tab and display the  test case count as 2 instead of 1 for the above case

1.Is there an option available in the allure cucumber reporter to disable the retries tab or customize the allure report?

I have tried to modify the scenario name in before hooks to include browser name but it has only getters, so I could not update

2.Is there an option to edit the feature name or scenario name during run time by appending browser details to them?

3.Any other reporting tool can be used in this place which provides as many as details as allure does

or any other possible solutions.